# How to handle heaps in C++

Tags: c++, stl, heap

I know this is probably one of those "you just have to try it" kind of questions, but since I do not have actual test data available yet, I'd like to get some input on your experience while I am still designing the code.

I have a data structure that implements a priority queue with some added functions. What I usually need to do is adding a bunch of objects to this heap at a time. I am using the `std::make_heap()`, `std::push_heap()` and `std::pop_heap()` algorithms to maintain the heap invariants.

For now whenever I do an insert I use `std::push_heap()` to add the single element. Now I am thinking about adding all the elements at a time, using the `std::vector::push_back()` method and then reorganizing the heap. A simple `push_heap()` at this time probably won't work so I would have to use a new `make_heap()`. However `make_heap()` runs in `(3*(last-first))` while `push_heap()` only takes `log(last-first)`.

Is there a simple way to figure out which one is actually faster in this case, or do I have to wait until test data becomes available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert *k* elements into a heap of size *n*, `make_heap()` will be faster roughly from the point where *k⋅log<sub>2</sub>(n) > 3⋅n*. That means when *k > 3⋅n / log<sub>2</sub>(n)*. You could calculate this value before a mass insertion and then decide what method will be faster.

Note that this value is only a rough estimation, because the actual implementation of the function probably won't take *exactly* these times to perform the operations. But it should be useful as a rule of thumb and get reasonably good results.

Answer (score 4):

`make_heap` runs with no more than 3N comparisons (where N is the size of the heap), while `push_heap` takes no more than log N.  However, you have to push each element into the heap separately, which means it takes N `push_heap`s, so that method is bounded by N log N comparisons.

Therefore, `make_heap` is asymptotically better than N `push_heap`s.  If the heap is large enough for initialization to matter in the first place, it's going to be better.

Comment: Assuming the queue is empty to start with.